# php thumbnail organizer

Tags: php, organizer

Ok, i have this code and is working perfectly, but i need the order of the images to be by the  date the image was created, can someone give me a hand?

```
$images=array();
$dir = @opendir('.') or die("Unable to open $path");
$i=0;
while($file = readdir($dir)) {
    if(is_dir($file))
        continue;
    else if($file != '.' && $file != '..' && $file != 'index.php') {
        $images[$i]=$file;
        $i++;
    }
}
sort($images);
for($i=0; $i<sizeof($images); $i++) {
    echo "<a href=".chr(34).$path.$images[$i].chr(34)."><img style='border:1px solid #666666; width:200px; margin: 10px;' src='".$images[$i]."'/></a>";
}
closedir($dir);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your index to $images is an integr index - why not make it the timestamp?

Answer (score 0):

Just use file's timestamp as the index and then sort the array by key.

Also, the right way to iterate over the list of files in a directory is [`DirectoryIterator`](http://php.net/directoryiterator):

```
$dir = new DirectoryIterator('.');
$images = array();

foreach ($dir as $file) {
    if ($file->isFile()) {
        $images[$file->getMTime()] = $file->getFilename();
    }
}

ksort($images);
```

Comment: Can you post exactly how the complete code will be? I know it's kinda lame to ask this but..

Comment: @brchannelbr My example is almost as complete as your original code. It does work correctly already. The further is up to rest of the logic in your application.